# Is my database transaction correct?

Tags: c#, mysql

My code is very slow I takes at least 10 sec to run this metod.
I have a arrayList with ingredients that I need to go through. 
for each of these ingredients I need to change the quantity in the database. All the items are in rawmaterials table. 
Is my code correct with respect to transaction ? Where should I do commit? 
In my code I am going to lock the whole table while I am updating the ingredients for one cookie

```
public void ProducePallet(string prodName, DateTime date)
{
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    cmd.CommandText =
        "INSERT INTO pallets(prodName,prodDate,blocked,orderID) VALUES(@name,@date, false, null)";
    cmd.Prepare();
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", prodName);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", date);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    cmd = new MySqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    cmd.CommandText =
        "Select mName, quantity from recipes natural join ingredients where prodName=@pName";
    cmd.Prepare();
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pName", prodName);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    ArrayList ingredients = new ArrayList();
    string[] ingredientsPair;
    MySqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (rdr.Read())
    {
        ingredientsPair = new string[2];
        ingredientsPair[0] = rdr.GetString(0); //Ingredient name
        ingredientsPair[1] = rdr.GetString(1); //Quantity
        ingredients.Add(ingredientsPair);

    }
    rdr.Close();
    MySqlTransaction tr = conn.BeginTransaction();
    foreach (string[] i in ingredients)
    {

        cmd = new MySqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandText = "Select quantityLeft from rawmaterials where mName=@mName for update";
        cmd.Prepare();
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mName", i[0]);
        rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        int mQuantity = 0;
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            mQuantity = rdr.GetInt32(0);
        }
        rdr.Close();
        mQuantity -= Int32.Parse(i[1]) * 36 * 10 * 15 / 100;
        //cmd = new MySqlCommand();
        //cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandText = "Update rawmaterials Set quantityLeft = @newQL where mName=@mName";
        cmd.Prepare();
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newQL", mQuantity);
        // cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mName", i[0]);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


    }

    try
    {

        tr.Commit();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        try
        {
            tr.Rollback();
        }
        catch (Exception e2)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(e2.ToString());
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

Raw material Table

```
 mName           quantityLeft
Bread crumbs    8959500
Butter  7782300
Chocolate   8946000
Chopped almonds 8623350
Cinnamon    8986500
Egg whites  8886600
Eggs    8867700
Fine-ground nuts    8757000
Flour   7774200
Ground, roasted nuts    8797500
Icing sugar 8780760
Marzipan    8716500
Potato starch   8990550
Roasted, chopped nuts   8829900
Sodium bicarbonate  8998920
Sugar   8446500
Vanilla 8999460
Vanilla sugar   8996220
Wheat flour 8990550
```

Comment: Execution plan please. And before we get into details - can you check whether the field mName has an index? if not - add one.

Comment: mName in Rawmaterials is primary key

Comment: Then anyone who considers helping you (I can not - not a mysql guy) Will need the query plan to see what the machine things it is doing. There is no reason this should take 10 seconds to run unless you either have hardware issues (like totally overloaded server) or a seriously bad application code somewhere else that locks rows in teh table for extended durations.

Comment: Is the DB local or remote to the system this is executing on? Do you know which part of this method takes the longest?

Comment: it isn't clear in the example... is there *at most one* row that could match this? is there any chance you're bringing back 20000 rows and just using the quantity from the last?

Comment: @MarcGravell Since `mName` is a primary key, that seems unlikely. Then again, maybe a string being a primary key is the issue here.

Comment: @jdphenix latency shouldn't cause a 10s delay unless the database is somewhere in the asteroid belt

Comment: @Asad I've learned never to rely on merely "unlikely" ;p

Comment: @user2975699 What datatype is `mName` set to in the DB? I hope it isn't something silly like `nvarchar(max)` or `text`?

Comment: DB is remote.
When i try to produce cookies in the program it takes long time. This code is from produce cookie method. 
I have codes to search in the database for different types of cookies they run very fast.

Comment: mName  is varchar(20);

Comment: By the way, it would be far more efficient to run the update directly at the database without ever fetching the value back - just send down the delta and `set quantityLeft = quantityLeft - @delta where ...`

Comment: Do a baseline server check please - memory usage (and mysql configuration), CPU usage and - IO usage and IO delay.

Comment: I have posted the whole method first part is fast second takes long time. one with foreach

Comment: @user2975699 Okay, that isn't too horrible unless you have a huge number of records, so it probably isn't responsible for all of the 10s delay. Still, have you considered using an int primary key? You can still enforce uniqueness on `mName` using an index.

Comment: Am i using Begin transactions and commit/rollback correctly?
should i move Begin transactions into foreach statement and do the same with commit and rollback?

Comment: @user2975699 I don't think you should be using a loop here at all. Updating a large number of records can be done using a single query, that way you avoid multiplying your latency overhead by the number of iterations.

Comment: Could u tell me how to do that without for loop?

Comment: @Asad and in the process, also avoid risking transaction entanglement between two connections accessing data - which could easily become a block, and quite often become a deadlock

Comment: @user2975699 This can probably be done in a single query, but I would need to know more about the schema of the `recipes` and `ingredients` tables to give you an exact answer. I can't discern the columns simply from looking at the queries because you're using `natural join`.

Comment: @MarcGravell I know, but something similar has happened to me that ended up being a network problem, so it might just something I've trained myself to check now

Answer (score 0):

Add "SET AUTOCOMMIT=0"; and "START TRANSACTION;" before starting the transaction.

Hope this will help you out.